# Automatically remove inactive durable consumers in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

For example, we have a durable topic consumer and some broker for that topic. As far as I understand that broker will continue to store every message (within some limits) even if that durable consumer is not active for a very long time.

Is there some broker's policy in ActiveMQ to destroy (auto unsubscribe) inactive (for some specified time) durable consumers? So that I don't need to monitor if all consumers still valid and actually exist.

Comment: Just curious as to why you would use a durable topic consumer if you think they are going to be offline so long that they would not become relevant anymore. If a "durable" consumer is not going to be online for a very long while and you don't care about it loosing messages, you might just use a normal consumer without makeing it durable..

Comment: They are not going to be offline. Some of durable consumers just may stop living at all (for example, due to some architecture changes). I don't want to monitor and remove every such consumer ID manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use **virtual topics** instead of durable consumers.

When using **virtual topic** all your messages from producer are sent the same way you send them now. However when a new consumer registers with a unique consumer name - a new queue is created for him, and all messages sent to virtual topic are duplicated into the queue. That means **each consumer has his own queue** - which is much more convenient than durable topic subscription.

Then when you know for sure your consumer no longer exists - you can delete the queue with all pending messages in it. It can be done whether from code or manually through AMQ web console or jconsole.

**EDIT:**
With virtual topic you get a new queue for every single consumer, therefore you can apply queue policy to delete it when inactive for a specified period of time.

In your activemq.xml set gcInactiveDestinations=true:

```
 <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
             <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" 
                      gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="10000"/>
```

Read more:
http://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html

Comment: thanks for response, I'll consider virtual topics. However, question was how to force ActiveMQ to automatically remove old/inactive consumers. Some kind of activity timeout.

Comment: Can't understand are these queues (one per consumer) provide the same behavior as a durable subscription. I mean I need them to deliver every missed (and only missed, not whole queue once again) messages after consumer restart. How that could be achieved? Persistent messages with some timeout?

Comment: Please read the following about virtual topics: 
http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html
and 
http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-difference-between-a-virtual-topic-and-a-composite-destination.html

They are in fact providing you with the same and even better functionality. Instead of ClientId you use unique consumer name in the queue you are subscribing to.

Comment: I'd read this before asking the question. I understand that there is a unique queue created per consumer (I even mentioned that in the previous comment). It's just not obvious for me how queue provides durability (in sense of durable topics). As far as I know queues don't track consumers (I mean something like: consumer A is now on message 20). I can't find some kind of "durable queue" in documentation.

Comment: Axiom: when using virtual topic queue is created for each consumer based on unique consumer name. Result: only one consumer is reading from the queue. When message is consumed is removed from the queue since it's been processed (similar to moving consumer to the next message - he will no longer be able to receive the consumed message). It is a regular queue but meant only for one consumer - no need for durability as it's implied. =)

Answer (score 4):

This is the options you need to set:

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000" offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="30000" offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="10000">
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is correct but will not work until you don't add schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000" at broker level. 
Every 10 seconds broker checks for inactive queues where no active consumer is connected and number of pending messages are zero. you can set it at higher value as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge policy is it possible to delete destination even though there are pending messages let say set a limit of 100 messages